# jquery menu issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Can someone help why this is not working when I click on menu link? When I click on menu it does not show the drop down menu.

Please view the code on this link [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEqs9/)

**Edit**

Now I changed it this code. Now when I click on menu link then it shows the drop down menu but when I click somewhere else then it does not hide it.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CEqs9/10/)

Comment: Please post your relevant code here.

Comment: the bug because you use the `.click()` event like `.hover()`

Comment: it work fine with hover  ,  i think you should use click and blur

Answer (score 3):

try this way:

```
$(function() {
        $('.top-nav li').click(function() {
            $('ul',this).toggle();
        });
    });
```

It looks like you have used the [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function syntax for [click](http://api.jquery.com/click/) which isn't going to work.

Also don't forget to `return false;` or the link will be followed. Or as an alternative you could use: [`e.preventdefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).

`return false` does both `e.preventDefault()` and [`e.stopPropagtion()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/). However in order to use `e` you should add the parameter to the function: `$('.top-nav li').click(function(e) {`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$(function() {
    $('.top-nav li a').click(function() {
        //this reveals the ul that is immediately after the clicked item
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    });
});​
```

You probably want to add a function to hide all other subnavs when one is revealed, otherwise you could have all of them open at once. This should do it:

```
$(function() {
    $('.top-nav li a').click(function() {
        //this hides all uls inside top-nav
        $('.top-nav ul').hide();
        //this reveals the ul that is immediately after the clicked item
        $(this).next('ul').toggle();
    });
});​
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I changed the trigger to li a. This way you can have "non-active" elements in top-nav. if trigger stays on li, then yes, you're right :)

Comment: The problem with this is when I click somewhere else I mean empty place it does not hide all the drop down menus.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function() {
  $("ul.top-nav li").click(function () {
    $('ul', this).css("display", "block");
  });

  $("ul.top-nav li").mouseleave(function () {
    $('ul', this).css("display", "none");
  });
});
```

Comment: using mouseleave, it does hide all the drop down menus.